# Renaming key in JSON

Tags: json

I have a JSON object that I am running though and throwing it into knockout to render labels for buttons. This is working fine, except when I am working to translate it into another language mainly because the key for the label is different.

Is there a way to rename a key that is coming in?

So far I have something like this.

```
var option = JSON.parse(this.model.get('Options')); //Gets the JSON
options = new Backbone.Collection(); //Turns it into a collection

for(var i = 0; i != option.length; ++i)
{
    delete option[i].Name; //This is the english name that I do not need so I am deleting it
    option[i].Code; //This is a value that has to be passed
    option[i].Name_spanish; //This is the spanish label that I would like to rename Name to take place of the english label.        
}
options.add(option); //This adds it to the collection
```

Any help would be appreciated. Just to make it a bit clearer. I have a Name varable I am deleting because that is the english name and I would like to rename that spanish label to Name so my knockout will read it.

Comment: Can you not simply do ``option[i].Name = option[i].Name_spanish`` and remove the `delete`?

Comment: @aruisdante, Yes thank you. This is proof that I have been stairing at this too hard and need a break. haha